# Flex: How does the compiler know about dependencies?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, mxml, mate

I'm completely new to Flex and am just having a play with a sample application from the Mate framework. I'm hacking on Linux so I'm using the command prompt and a text editor rather than Flex Builder.

The sample app has two folders in its root directory lib & src. Lib contains a dependency. How can I compile the mxml file in src, so that the compiler knows about the dependency in lib?

At the moment I'm running $ mxmlc sampleApp/src/sampleApp.mxml

The compiler throws an exception saying that is couldn't resolve  to a component implementation. I know this component is part of the dependency in the lib folder. So it is obviously not being picked up automatically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the path to the libraries, this can be done by either using a command line argument or putting it in a configuration file. See:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/compilers_19.html#158337